# How objects are stored in NSData? Will the data size (in bytes) be the same as before storing as NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, encoding, nsdata

To expand my question, I have an `NSString` that contains a URL to a video file that weighs 2MB. I use `dataWithContentsOfURL` to store it in the form of `NSData`. I added a breakpoint and checked out the size of the data. It was way damn high (more than **12MB**), just took the bytes and did math on it (**data/1024/1024**).

Then I save the data as a video file with `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` and I used `attributesOfItemAtPath` to get `FileSize` attribute of that saved file. It is showing up correctly (2MB). All I want to know is, how the objects are encoded. Why this drastic change in size (in bytes) when converting URL to a data file.

Comment: How exactly did you determine the NSData object was 12MB?

Comment: Added a breakpoint and hovered over the data object. It gave me this: `<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x1748646c0] = { leaf, size = 13318680, buf = 0x10b93c000 }>`

I just took the size.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code for creating and populating your `NSData` object. And log the `length` property of the data. What is its value?

Comment: when you convert in NSData form. it's size will increase.

Answer (score 1):

> All I want to know is, how the objects are encoded. Why this drastic change in size (in bytes) when converting URL to a data file.

An `NSData` is not "encoded" in any way, the bytes stored in one are the raw bytes. There is some overhead in the structure, but this is small.

Reading in a 2MB file will take a little more than 2MB, the overhead is small enough that you might not notice it in the memory usage. You can read much larger files than this and see no significant memory usage growth above the file size.

Your increase in memory usage is due to something else. Accidental multiple copies of the `NSData`? Maybe you are unintentionally uncompressing compressed video? Etc. You'll have to hunt for the cause.